# How do i copy files to virtual path at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am loading a user control dynamically like below

```
UserControl objUserControl = (UserControl)this.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ucProfileViewDefault.ascx");
```

Now I have another user control file ucProfileViewSMSIS.ascx which is located in some other location . I need to copy this file to my virtual path at run time and then load it like below

```
UserControl objUserControl = (UserControl)this.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ucProfileViewSMSIS.ascx");
```

How do i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) and `Page.ResloveUrl` will get you the location, then you can move it and load:

```
var path = Server.MapPath(Page.ResolveUrl("~/UserControls/ucProfileViewSMSIS.ascx"));
```